# Truncate value label of PieChart in Charts Library Swift

Tags: swift, charts, pie-chart, ios-charts

`class PieChartViewController: DemoBaseViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var chartView: PieChartView!
@IBOutlet var sliderX: UISlider!
@IBOutlet var sliderY: UISlider!
@IBOutlet var sliderTextX: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var sliderTextY: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Pie Chart"
    self.setup(pieChartView: chartView)
    
    chartView.delegate = self
    chartView.holeRadiusPercent = 0.8
    chartView.usePercentValuesEnabled = true
    chartView.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0
    chartView.drawHoleEnabled = true
    chartView.transparentCircleColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)
    chartView.drawCenterTextEnabled = true
    chartView.centerText = nil
    let l = chartView.legend
    l.enabled = false
    
    
    //MARK: Entry label Styling (Value Label Above PieChart)
    chartView.entryLabelColor = .black
    chartView.entryLabelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
    
    //MARK: Setting Offset
    let frameOffset = chartView.frame.width * 0.12
    chartView.setExtraOffsets(left: frameOffset, top: frameOffset, right: frameOffset, bottom: frameOffset)
    
    self.slidersValueChanged(nil)
}

override func updateChartData() {
    if self.shouldHideData {
        chartView.data = nil
        return
    }
    self.setDataCount()
}

func setDataCount() {
    
    let entry1 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 22, label: "Apple.It is a fruit")
    let entry2 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 33, label: "Zebra.It is an animal")
    let entry3 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 31, label: "Eagle.It is a bird")
    let entry4 = PieChartDataEntry(value: 14, label: "Asia.It is a continent")
    
    var enteries: [PieChartDataEntry] = []
    enteries.append(entry1)
    enteries.append(entry2)
    enteries.append(entry3)
    enteries.append(entry4)
    
    let set = PieChartDataSet(entries: enteries, label: "Knowledge")
    set.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set.sliceSpace = 0
    set.selectionShift = 0
    
    
    set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.vordiplom()
        + ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
        + ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        + ChartColorTemplates.liberty()
        + ChartColorTemplates.pastel()
        + [UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 181/255, blue: 229/255, alpha: 1)]
    
    // MARK: Setting Value Label
    
    set.valueLinePart1OffsetPercentage = 0.20
    set.valueLinePart1Length = 0.4
    set.valueLinePart2Length = 0.4
    set.valueLineColor = .black
    set.valueTextColor = .black
    set.xValuePosition = .outsideSlice
    set.yValuePosition = .outsideSlice
    
    let data = PieChartData(dataSet: set)
    data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium))
    data.setValueTextColor(.black)
    
    chartView.data = data
    chartView.highlightValues(nil)
}

override func optionTapped(_ option: Option) {
    chartView.setNeedsDisplay()
}

// MARK: - Actions
@IBAction func slidersValueChanged(_ sender: Any?) {
    self.updateChartData()
}
```

}`

**How to truncate or word wrap the value label in Pie Chart ?**

- I am using Charts Library in iOS.

  If I add extra offset the pie chart shrink in smaller devices like iPhone 5s or iPhone SE.
  If the text is large then the text goes out of the screen as you can see in the uploaded image.
   I am not able to find any properties (word wrap) to handle the large text issue.

[image]

Comment: Please share your label code as an [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: Please don't overuse tags, going to remove Objective-C tag, this is Swift.

Comment: I'd also recommend to fill an issue (question) [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) where you'll get an answer more likely. It might be already answered, don't know, you can search issues.